# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ..." when trying to make unit tests in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, directory

## Problem

I am trying to make unit tests for my project, but I am having issues figuring out where my error is in regards to absolute importing the module to test. I am using Visual Studio Code as my IDE.

My directories look like this:

`project_folder`
  `+ code_files` 
      `- reader.py` 
      `- __init__.py` 
  `+ tests` 
      `- test_reader.py` 
      `- data.txt`
      `- __init__.py`

My "test_reader.py" file looks like this:

`import unittest` 
`from code_files.reader import Reader` 
                                            
`class Test_LineCounter(unittest.TestCase):` 
  `def test_empty_file_long(self):` 
     `self.assertEqual(Reader.line_counter(self, "data.txt"), 4)`
                                            
`if __name__ == "__main__":`
  `unittest.main()`

However, I keep getting the error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code_files'`

## Attempted Solutions

To be completely honest, when I was going into this project I was not very strong working with directories, packages, or modules. I have read many articles online and have read many forum posts on Stack Overflow and other websites trying to figure out what may be causing this error and how I can resolve it. Through this, I feel like I have gained a pretty good understanding of how Python handles packages and modules. Yet I still can't seem to get this problem figured out.

I have tried putting the "code_files" package into a different directory to see if that would work:

`project_folder`
  `+ app` 
      `+ code_files` 
          `- reader.py` 
          `- __init__.py`

And then imported by:

`from app.code_files.reader import Reader`

But then I got the error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

The only time I managed to get "test_reader" to work was when I had my directory structed as follows:

`project_folder`
  `+ code_files` 
      `- reader.py` 
      `- __init__.py` 
  `+ test_reader.py` 
  `+ data.txt`
  `+ __init__.py`

## Final Comments

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I feel like there is a very simple solution to this that I just keep overlooking. I know very similar questions have been asked on here before, but all of the determined solutions I have seen are what I have already tried or am currently doing. So I apologize if this is a repetitive question. Thanks!

Comment: [Run the tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface) from `project_folder`, don't call the modules in `tests` directly!

Comment: just a quick tip : you can put your code blocks in code fences instead of code samples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Reason:**

This is because the folder of `project_folder` was not in the [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?path#sys.path).

> A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules.
> Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an
> installation-dependent default.
>
> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list,
> path[0], is the **directory containing the script that was used to**
> **invoke the Python interpreter**.

This can explain the problem you have met.

When the `test_reader.py` is under the `tests` folder, `tests` folder will be added to the `sys.path`. When the `test_reader.py` is under the `project_folder` folder, `project_folder` folder will be added to the `sys.path`. Then the python interpreter can find the `code_files` package.

**Solution:**

How do you run the test? If you run the test through the Test Panel you will not run across the module problem:

[image]

And it will automatically add the workspace folder to the `sys.path`. So, it's recommended to run the test in this way.

**tips:**

> If you want to get the `sys.path`, you can add the `pprint(sys.path)`
> after the `self.assertEqual(Reader.line_counter(self, "data.txt"), 4)`. But you can only get the result in the channel of `Python Test Log` in the `OUTPUT` panel.

If you debug(F5) the test, you can add this in the launch.json file:

**"env": {"PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceFolder}"},**

If you run the test with the command in ter terminal. You should modify the `sys.path` in the test file:

```
sys.path.append("the path to the project_folder folder")
```

Comment: @Levino hope to hear your response.

Comment: While the solution you offered is true, in my case it was not working as I was still encountering the problem when running my test through the Test Panel (Python: Discover Tests was unable to locate tests -- I should have mentioned that in my original post as well). What ended up working for me was putting: "sys.path.append("..")" in the beginning of my test file and then importing my code by using "from code_files.reader import Reader". Your reason that you gave was extremely helpful and was what put me on the right track to find the answers I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You must add this to the beginning of test_reader.py

```
# test_reader.py
import sys
sys.path.append('/.../project_folder/code_files')
import reader
```

Replace the `...` with the concrete path, so if it is in Desktop on Windows then it would be 'C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/project_folder' and so on...

[Here is a link to further information](https://blog.finxter.com/python-how-to-import-modules-from-another-folder/)

Comment: This is only a solution if you only ever want to run it on your machine. This would not work as soon it's deployed to a CI/CD server.